# How to reset dynamically generated php array's key?

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I have a dynamically generated array with about 25 numeric values selected from a database table column. I am then retrieving these values for later use with a foreach function like this:

```
$array[] = $row['table_colum_name'];
foreach( $array as $key => $value){
$$key = $value;
$value1 = $array['0'];
$value2 = $array['1'];
...
$value25 = $array['24'];
```

Problem is sometimes, for certain queries, there are less than 25 values returned to $array[], which creates a problem in getting the right $value results by using the keys as above. For example, if there is no result found at position 24, then $array['23'] will actually be populated with the result of $array['24'], which will mess up the whole set of results downstream from it.

I tried the following to see if there is a result for a particular key:

```
if (array_key_exists('23', $array)) {
echo "The '23' element is present in the array";
}
```

but it doesn't seem to be able to pick up cases in which there is a missing key/value.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the point of doing this `$$key = $value; $value1 = $array['0'];` ? Why do not use arrays itself?

Comment: The reason was I wanted to make sure I had the right keys present, while trying to debug the issue. I could use the array itself, but I still run into the same issue.

Comment: Why dont you use array_values and the in your loop $value[$key]=something ? But then why dont you use the array itself ?

Comment: I can use the array itself, @cpugourou. The issue still remains, though, as I said: if one of the results is empty, it messes up all the results downstream from it.

Comment: If so just count the array and set the loop limit based on it ?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, @cpugourou, will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to provide a code example that will work perfectly, since your question and your code above leave a few details out, but basically, if I'm interpreting your question correctly, something very similar to this should work:

```
for( $x = 1; $x <= 25; $x++ ) {
    $foo = 'value' . $x;

    if ( isset( $array[$x-1])) {
        $$foo = $array[$x-1];
    }
    else {
        $$foo = '';
    }
}
```

So assuming your array has indices in the range '0' to '24', with possibly a few entries missing, you will end up with the variables `$value1` through to `$value25` set with the corresponding elements from the array (eg. $value1 = $array['0'], etc) but where there is a missing element (eg. array['6']) then the corresponding variable (eg. $value7) will get set to a null string.

I think this is just about the clearest, most defensive solution I could think of.

**UPDATE**

Updated version based on new information in comments:

```
foreach( $array as $key => value ) {
    $foo = 'value' . $key + 1;

    if ( isset( $array[$key])) {
        $$foo = $array[$key];
    }
    else {
        $$foo = '';
    }
}
```

So if you want `$value204` to be set to the value of `$array['203']` when `$array['203']` exists, leave the `+ 1` in the second line.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @JamesG! It looks promising. I should have mentioned though that the array elements are not consecutive numbers, but rather a sequence of numbers between 203 and 646, arranged incrementally. How would you write the code above for such a sequence?

Comment: So just to check, if $array[203] exists then $value204 should be set to whatever the value of $array[203] is?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all again for your answers.

In the end, what I ended up doing was to move my solution up into the SQL search and use a right outer join to keep the null results when they occur, which manages to keep the array count constant, which in turn allows me to retrieve array values in a predictable, consistent fashion.